# ACF - How to exclude current page from acf relationship query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have acf option page with the field Relationship. I display this block on many pages of the site. How can I exclude the current page from the list of displayed pages?

My code for Relationship:

```
         <?php $coin_pages = get_field('sb_sector_pages_pages', 'option');
            if( $coin_pages ): 
            foreach( $coin_pages as $post ) : 
                $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );
                $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full');
                $title = get_the_title( $post->ID );
                setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <li class="coin-article__sidebar-list-item">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_html( $permalink ); ?>" class="coin-article__sidebar-list-link">
                            <div class="coin-article__sidebar-coin-ico">
                                <?php echo $thumbnail; ?>
                            </div>
                            <span class="coin-article__sidebar-coin-title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I tried to add this to my functions.php but it doesn’t work for me:

```
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=sb_sector_pages_pages', 'exclude_id', 10, 3);
function exclude_id ( $args, $field, $post ) {
        $args['post__not_in'] = array( $post );
        return $args;
}
```

How to exclude a current page from the ACF relationship query??

Comment: you can use `continue` if the postID matches the current postid

Comment: Do you mean after setupe_post_darta create a check if the $permalink matches the current URL and if so continue? Because I tried this and it doesn't work(

Comment: I would do it before. have your current posts id in a variable, and check if it matches `$post->ID` if so, continue

Comment: The `$post` variable name is bad practice since it's a global variable. use `$_post` or any other variable name and do use `wp_reset_postdata()`  after `foreach` as you're using `setup_postdata`